# How should I prove $(a+b)^3= a^3+3ab(a+b)+b^3$ --- Model or figure?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, geometry

In what way can I prove/verify $(a+b)^3= a^3+3ab(a+b)+b^3$ ? Should I make a 3D model, or create 2D figure? In the case of 3D model, I have made $a^3$ and $b^3$; i.e cube'a' and cube'b'. I don't know what to do with $3a^2b+ 3b^2a$, in case I'm making a model. Previously, I made a figure by cutting paper pieces to verify $(a+b+c)^2$. I want to know whether model can be made or not. If not, then how must I prove $(a+b)^3=a^3+3ab(a+b)+b^3$ ?

Comment: Use a cube of side $a+b$, with cubes of sides $a$ and $b$ inside and at opposite corners. (Of course we are assuming $a,b\gt 0$.) The identity, geometrically proved in this way, was used by Cardano in his famous solution of the cubic.

Comment: [Pretty picture](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0f/BinomialTheorem.png).

Comment: You could also use algebra.

Comment: The problem with picture proofs is that they only work for $a,b\ge 0$.

Comment: See [The Geometry of the Binomial Theorem](http://www.math.brown.edu/~banchoff/Beyond3d/chapter2/section04.html) or at [this web page](http://montessorimuddle.org/2012/02/page/4/) see *Using the Binomial Cube in Algebra*.

Comment: A model will surely look cool. You can color each type of blocks $a^3$, $a^2 b$ etc.

Comment: Thank you, @AndréNicolas Nicolas for the beautiful suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @DaveL.Renfro for the two interesting websites!

Comment: You are welcome. Happily, pictures were supplied that are much better than my brief verbal description.

Comment: Thanks very much @Lucian for the '' Pretty picture'' ! It helped me a lot in solving my problem!

Comment: @LeeMosher , thanks a lot for suggesting me ideas and telling me the problem.

Comment: Thanks again, @AndréNicolas! Your verbal description were important and useful too!

Comment: Thanks for informing the problem, @lhf!

Comment: Thanks for the nice comment, and cool idea, @PA6OTA

Comment: ********** THANKS ALL FOR YOUR IDEAS AND COMMENTS!!! IT REALLY HELPED ME FOR MY PROJECT! I'M SURE I'LL GET FULL MARKS FOR THIS ONE BECAUSE OF YOUR HELP!!! **********

Comment: Anooja, you might be interested in a classroom experience I had with this topic. See towards the end of [this 3 May 2010 math-teach post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7056499) at Math Forum.

Comment: Thank you very much, @DaveL.Renfro, for , I'll surely use your methods on which you wrote. Very inspirational. And, I'll surely tell my teacher to do the same ( I am a student!). This is really interesting and fun!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ya,it could be explained by a model also. See my drawings below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for this diagram! I appreciate, @Sagnik Saha.

Answer (score 18):

[image]
[image]

$\phantom{Body must be at least 30 characters; you entered 0.}$

Comment: Thanks for explaining this very simple! I can understand now easily, @Rahul

Comment: @Sagnik: False.

Comment: @Sagnik: Well, this is certainly the most petty series of comments I have ever had the misfortune of receiving. On the bright side, all other comments I get in the future will look incredibly gracious in comparison, so thanks for that.

Comment: Nice job, Rahul, your pic was what I had in mind but too lazy to produce ;0

Comment: What did you use in order to create this image?

Comment: @bzm3r In the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/644612/219947), you may find `tikz` versions of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Yes model can be made.
Make cuboid whose length, bredth and height are a,a,a resp. For $a^3$ similarly for $b^3$
and $a^2b$ means a,a,b.

Comment: Thanks really, @DSinghvi for explaining me the measurements!!!

Comment: ***** THANKS EVERYONE FOR THE DIAGRAMS AND EXPLANATIONS AND SITES *****